# Efficient way to load multiple lat/long from div to function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got 10+ divs on a page and I dynamically load single marker lat/long data into each div, onclick. This produces a map, no problems. I am trying to get it so that I can parse multiple values of lat/long data into each div. Here is an example with single lat/long entry data

DEMO JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2441/

```
<div id="map1" class="map" data-no="1" data-lat="53.716216" data-long="-1.96312"></div>
```

and here's my attempt using multiple markers per div

DEMO JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2445/

```
<div id="map1" class="map" data-no="1" data-loc="53.716216,-1.582031|53.815121,-1.96312"></div>
```

It does not work and I am at a dead end on how to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post your code, not just jsfiddles.  http://jsfiddle.net/bj674/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The marker position needs to be a google.maps.LatLng, not a comma separated string
- the map needs to be initialized before using in the markerOptions
- (among other things).

`function mapOneInitialize(elem, index,loc) {`

```
    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng('53.716216,-1.582031')

    var options = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: centerPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map[index] = new google.maps.Map(elem, options);

    var loc = loc.split("|");
    for (var x = 0; x < loc.length; x++) {
        var coords = loc[x].split(',');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),
                                             parseFloat(coords[1])),
            map: map[index]
        });
    }
};
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj674/1/)